# What does "receivePortSync is not defined" mean?

Tags: dart

I just tried to run an older Dart app, and I received this error:

```
Breaking on exception: ReferenceError: ReceivePortSync is not defined
```

Where does this exception come from, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see `ReceivePortSync is not defined`, this means you're missing the `interop.js` script.

Simply add this:

```
<script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>
```

Before the `</body>` tag of your page.

Also, you'll want to double check you have the `js` package as a dependency in your pubspec.yaml. Something like:

```
name: my_app
dependencies:
  js: any
```